# I want to read line only if it starts with a specific character

Tags: .net, vb.net, io

I have a text file as shown below

```
O "ABC123.GEO"
O "A83.GEO"
O "A765.GEO"
@ "A38456.geo"
@ "RX34.geo"
1 entries Of @ "A756473.geo" added In New data
```

I want to read only the lines that starts with @

I am doing this is VB.NET

Comment: [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: You can create an array containing all the lines beginning with "@": `Dim myLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(My_Text_File).Where(Function(ln) ln.StartsWith("@")).ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str as string = ""
Using sr as new io.streamReader(path)
  While sr.Peek <> -1
  Str = sr.Readline()
    If str.startswith("@")   
      ' Do action
    End if
  END While
End Using
```